# How can I add links to other controller methods in generated OpenAPI specs using attributes in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

I am using SwaggerGen to generate an OpenAPI spec for our API, and would like to add links between certain endpoints.

[OpenAPI 3.0 Links](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/links/)

Is there a way to add an attribute to the controller method that links to another controller method?

For example, if I currently have something like

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("~/users")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ResponseObject<UserId>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser(...)
{
    // Create user
}


[HttpGet]
[Route("~/users/{userId}")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ResponseObject<User>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser(...)
{
    // Get newly created user
}
```

Could I somehow link them like

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("~/users")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ResponseObject<UserId>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[Link(nameof(GetUser), "UserId")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser(...)
{
    // Create user
}


[HttpGet]
[Route("~/users/{userId}")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ResponseObject<User>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser(...)
{
    // Get newly created user
}
```

to generate the "links" field as shown in the OpenAPI 3.0 spec linked above?

Comment: It seems that is not been implemented yet [OpenAPI links](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1324)

Comment: That's a shame, I'd like to contribute sometime, but I wonder if there's a way I can simulate the functionality some other way